# Two tags with the same meaning: [android-ibeacon] and [ibeacon-android]

Tags: discussion, tags

On SO I searched for `iBeacon` and I found questions with both 
[android-ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-ibeacon) and [ibeacon-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-android).

I am little confused, if both are for Android then why are they separate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there are three iBeacon tags.

[android-ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-ibeacon) [ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon) and [ibeacon-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-android).

It seems that iBeacon is available for iOS and android, as well as raspberry-pi and other systems. IMO [android-ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-ibeacon) and [ibeacon-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-android) can be synonymed to [ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon), because the [ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon) tag can be combined with a platform tag to find questions about [ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon) that relate to that specific platform.

Otherwise, we would end up with [ibeacon-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-android) [ibeacon-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-ios) [ibeacon-raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon-raspberry-pi) etc... which just seems way too disorganized.

Comment: Aside from Android tag's culture of prefixing something with [tag:android-], I agree that those should be synonymized/burnt, since iBeacon is a technology, not from Android, and is officially **not** supported for Android (exclusive to Apple [based on this article](http://beekn.net/2014/07/ibeacon-for-android/)).